# Executing the command instead of printing

Tags: unix

The following command "prints" the correct mysql commands. But I want to "execute" them :)

```
mysqlshow -uroot -pPassWord | awk '{print "mysqlshow -uroot -pPassWord --count", $2;}

mysqlshow -uroot -pPassWord --count world
mysqlshow -uroot -pPassWord --count zabbix
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mysqlshow -uroot -pPassWord | awk '{print "mysqlshow -uroot -pPassWord --count", $2;} | sh
```